# How do I get the Parent Category of the current Category Im on for Custom post type Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

If my Current Structure is as follows : product-category/accessories/face-mask/

I can get Face-Mask Writter out by just saying: echo single_cat_title( '', true );

But I want to output Accessories (Or whatever Parent there is to the current category)

Everything I find about this is extremely extensive And I quite simply just dont get half of it so wondering if someone could explain to me how this works and how u do it?

When I try to do something like:

```
$categoryz = get_the_category(); 
echo $categoryz[0]->cat_ID;
$topCat = get_category_parents($categoryz);
```

And then output topCat I get `Trying to get property 'cat_ID' of non-object`

Answer (score 1):

try using `term_id` or you can use `get_queried_object()`

```
$categoryz = get_the_category(); 
$topCat    = get_category_parents($categoryz[0]->term_id);
```

OR

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$parent_cat_id = $cat->parent;
```

OR

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$parentcats = get_ancestors( $cat->term_id, $cat->taxonomy );
```